# Dask losing workers over time

Tags: graph, dask

Here is the mcve to demonstrate losing workers over time. This is a followup to

[Distributing graphs to across cluster nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46023458/distributing-graphs-to-across-cluster-nodes)

The example is not quite minimal but it does give an idea of our typical work patterns. The sleep is necessary to cause the problem. This occurs in the full application because of the need to generate a large graph from previous results.

When I run this on a cluster, I use dask-ssh to get 32 workers over 8 nodes:

```
dask-ssh --nprocs 4 --nthreads 1 --scheduler-port 8786 --log-directory `pwd` --hostfile hostfile.$JOBID &
sleep 10
```

It should run in less than about 10 minutes with the full set of workers. I follow the execution on the diagnostics screen. Under events, I see the workers being added but then I sometimes but not always see removal of a number of workers, usually leaving only those on the node hosting the scheduler.

```
""" Test to illustrate losing workers under dask/distributed.

This mimics the overall structure and workload of our processing.

Tim Cornwell 9 Sept 2017
realtimcornwell@gmail.com
"""
import numpy
from dask import delayed
from distributed import Client


# Make some randomly located points on 2D plane
def init_sparse(n, margin=0.1):
    numpy.random.seed(8753193)
    return numpy.array([numpy.random.uniform(margin, 1.0 - margin, n),
                        numpy.random.uniform(margin, 1.0 - margin, n)]).reshape([n, 2])


# Put the points onto a grid and FFT, skip to save time
def grid_data(sparse_data, shape, skip=100):
    grid = numpy.zeros(shape, dtype='complex')
    loc = numpy.round(shape * sparse_data).astype('int')
    for i in range(0, sparse_data.shape[0], skip):
        grid[loc[i,:]] = 1.0
    return numpy.fft.fft(grid).real

# Accumulate all psfs into one psf
def accumulate(psf_list):
    lpsf = 0.0 * psf_list[0]
    for p in psf_list:
        lpsf += p
    return lpsf


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    import time
    start=time.time()

    # Process nchunks each of length len_chunk 2d points, making a psf of size shape
    len_chunk = int(1e6)
    nchunks = 16
    shape=[512, 512]
    skip = 100

    # We pass in the scheduler from the invoking script
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        scheduler = sys.argv[1]
        client = Client(scheduler)
    else:
        client = Client()

    print("On initialisation", client)

    sparse_graph = [delayed(init_sparse)(len_chunk) for i in range(nchunks)]
    sparse_graph = client.compute(sparse_graph, sync=True)
    print("After first sparse_graph", client)

    xfr_graph = [delayed(grid_data)(s, shape=shape, skip=skip) for s in sparse_graph]
    xfr = client.compute(xfr_graph, sync=True)
    print("After xfr", client)

    tsleep = 120.0
    print("Sleeping now for %.1f seconds" % tsleep)
    time.sleep(tsleep)
    print("After sleep", client)

    sparse_graph = [delayed(init_sparse)(len_chunk) for i in range(nchunks)]
    # sparse_graph = client.compute(sparse_graph, sync=True)
    xfr_graph = [delayed(grid_data)(s, shape=shape, skip=skip) for s in sparse_graph]
    psf_graph = delayed(accumulate)(xfr_graph)
    psf = client.compute(psf_graph, sync=True)

    print("*** Successfully reached end in %.1f seconds ***" % (time.time() - start))
    print(numpy.max(psf))
    print("After psf", client)

    client.shutdown()
    exit()
```

Grep'ing a typical run for Client shows:

```
On initialisation <Client: scheduler='tcp://sand-8-17:8786' processes=16 cores=16>
After first sparse_graph <Client: scheduler='tcp://sand-8-17:8786' processes=16 cores=16>
After xfr <Client: scheduler='tcp://sand-8-17:8786' processes=16 cores=16>
After sleep <Client: scheduler='tcp://sand-8-17:8786' processes=4 cores=4>
After psf <Client: scheduler='tcp://sand-8-17:8786' processes=4 cores=4>
```

Thanks,
Tim

Comment: We are still struggling with this. We see `[ worker openhpc-compute-1 ] : distributed.core - WARNING - Event loop was unresponsive for 1.12s.  This is often caused by long-running GIL-holding functions or moving large chunks of data. This can cause timeouts and instability.
[ scheduler openhpc-compute-0:8786 ] : distributed.scheduler - INFO - Worker 'tcp://10.60.253.19:39025' failed from closed comm: in <closed TCP>: TimeoutError: [Errno 110] Connection timed out
[ scheduler openhpc-compute-0:8786 ] : distributed.scheduler - INFO - Remove worker tcp://10.60.253.19:39025`

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite clear why this works but it did. We were using dask-ssh but needed more control over the creation of the workers. Eventually we settled on:

```
scheduler=$(head -1 hostfile.$JOBID)
hostIndex=0
for host in `cat hostfile.$JOBID`; do
    echo "Working on $host ...."
    if [ "$hostIndex" = "0" ]; then
        echo "run dask-scheduler"
        ssh $host dask-scheduler --port=8786 &
        sleep 5
    fi
    echo "run dask-worker"
    ssh $host dask-worker --host ${host} --nprocs NUMBER_PROCS_PER_NODE \
    --nthreads NUMBER_THREADS  \
    --memory-limit 0.25 --local-directory /tmp $scheduler:8786 &
    sleep 1
    hostIndex="1"
done
echo "Scheduler and workers now running"
```